# Unable to print output from a python function

Tags: python

I made a simple function to identify the tennis player who served the last point in a tie-breaker match. Below is my code, which returns the player but when I am printing the result, I get None.

```
def get_tie_break_point_server(s,tie_break_sum,playerA,playerB):

  s = s+1
  if(s == tie_break_sum):
      return playerB
  s = s+1
  if(s == tie_break_sum):
      return playerB
  else :
      get_tie_break_point_server(s,tie_break_sum,playerB,playerA)

tie_break_score = [2, 2]
playerA = "A"
playerB = "B"
tie_break_sum = tie_break_score[0] + tie_break_score[1]
print get_tie_break_point_server(1,tie_break_sum,playerA,playerB)
```

Comment: Related questions: [Why does my recursive function return "None"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17286808), [Recursive function returning none?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31739963), [Why Python recursive function returns None](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31221826), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns `None` when it reaches the last 'else' block.  When a function reaches the end of its code block without an explicit `return` statement it will implicitly return `None`.  You need to change the last line to

```
return get_tie_break_point_server(s,tie_break_sum,playerB,playerA)
```